# insert data to Fuseki with sparql query

Tags: java, spring-boot, sparql, jena, fuseki

I am trying to insert new data to Fuseki through SPARQL query, it's giving me success(200 OK) but it's not showing in my TDB. and I think it's because I haven't defined to which graph but I don't know-how

```
    String queryString =          
          "PREFIX ns:<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/unit#>" 
                    + "PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>" 
                    + "INSERT DATA{" 
                    + "ns:" + d.getDomainName()+ "ns:domainName " + d.getDomainName() + "." 
                    + "ns:" + d.getDomainName() + " ns:domainId "+ d.getDomainId() + "." 
                    + "}";

            UpdateRequest request = UpdateFactory.create(queryString);
            UpdateProcessor qe = UpdateExecutionFactory.createRemote(request,
                    "http://localhost:3030/eduDataSet/update");
            qe.execute();
```

Comment: how do you check if it's not in the database? I also suggest to use `RDFConnection` nowadays: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/rdfconnection/

Comment: you can do `select * where {{graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}} union {?s ?p ?o }}` to see if any data is in the database

Comment: I check using query on Fuseki UI direct. I think my problem is the insert sparql query format. would rdfconnection solve that, can you give an example?

Comment: so, did you run the query I posted? What is the result of it? Also, your namespace declaration is a bit odd, i.e. `PREFIX ns:<example-ns>` - please use proper URIs.

Comment: An example is given in the link I posted, see paragraph "Update Usage" there. Might not solve your problem, but it's the better way to go when using Jena nowadays I guess.

Comment: @UninformedUser I edited the prefix. and the query result is all the graph

Comment: MY question was more, is your inserted data in the returned resultset or not?

Comment: What's the configuration of "http://localhost:3030/eduDataSet/" because if it has "unionDefaultGraph true" then you wil see you data in a query because it is not in a named graph. Try `select * where {graph <urn:x-arq:DefaultGraph> { ?s ?p ?o }}` or add `GRAPH <ns:myData> { .... }` to the data part of `INSERT DATA` or remove the "unionDefaultGraph true".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to reformat your queryString as shown in this picture.

[image]

[reference](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SPARQL-Update/#rInsertTemplate)

be careful where to close your subject
"PREFIX ns:<http://www.semanticweb.org/hightech/ontologies/2019/unit#>"  <== is already closed, while you need to insert your d.getDomainName() before closing ">"

Comment: I tried to do it like this example 
 ` "INSERT DATA{" + "<"+ OntologyManagerWithFusekiApplication.ns + d.getDomainId() + "> ns:domainName \""+ d.getDomainName() + "\"." 
                 + "<"+ OntologyManagerWithFusekiApplication.ns + d.getDomainId() + "> ns:domainId \"" + d.getDomainId() + "\"." 
                 + "}";
`
but still not working, lexical syntax error

Comment: try this one : "INSERT DATA{"  +  "<" + OntologyManagerWithFusekiApplication.ns + d.getDomainId() + "> ns:domainName \""+ d.getDomainName() + "\";"  + "ns:domainId \"" + d.getDomainId() + "\"." + "}";